Sending confidential email from Thunderbird
On the browser version of Gmail, I can send a confidential email that is

time limited
cant be forwarded
cant be printed
cant be copied
cant be downloaded

Is there a way to get Thunderbird to use this feature?

No. The feature doesn't send a standard message; it is a Gmail-specific service, and since there is no mention of it in https://developers.google.com it means the feature is not accessible to external software.
(It also doesn't prevent the message from being saved as a screenshot...)
